# While Loop For Table Rows From MySQL With Colour Coded Cells Based On Score

Tags: php

I have a MySQL table of results of collected responses on a form that I want to output in a table.

The user rates certain variables such as Sleep from good (1) to bad (7) and each users results are on each row.

I did that successfully, but to make it more readable I want to colour code the scores based on score.

E.g., if you score 2 or below the table cell should be green, and if you score 6 or above it is coloured red.

There are 5 different variables being rated so not sure if the method I am using would work or if something more suitable.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Responses";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<tr>';

        if($row['Sleep'] <= 2)
        {
            echo "<td style='background-color: green;'>" . $row['Sleep'] . "</td>";

        }
        elseif ($row['Sleep'] >= 6)
        {
            echo "<td style='background-color: red;'>" . $row['Sleep'] . "</td>";

        }

        else
        {
            echo "<td>" . $row['Sleep'] . "</td>";

        }

        echo '</tr>';

    }
```

No output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so

```
function getColor($number)
{
    if ($numner <= 2)
        return 'green';
    else if ($numner > 2 && $var < 6)
        return 'black';
    else if ($number >= 6)
        return 'red';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Responses";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td>' . $row["Name"] . '</td>';

    echo '<td style="background-color: "' . $getColor($row["Sleep"]) . '">' . $row["Sleep"] . '</td>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just put your different variables in an array

```
function getColor($number)
    {
        if ($number <= 2)
            return 'green';
        else if ($number > 2 && $number < 6)
            return 'none';
        else if ($number >= 6)
            return 'red';
    }


echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //replace var* with your variable
    $variables = array("Sleep", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5");

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["Name"] . '</td>';
    $i=0;
    while($i<5)
    {
      $score=$row[$variables[$i]];
      echo '<td style="background-color: ' . getColor($score). ';">' . $score . '</td>';
      $i++;
    }
echo '</tr>';

}
echo "</table>";
```